# jest.setTimeout.Error: Mocking Express middleware with Jest and Supertest

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I would like to mock the auth middleware function to always just call `next()`. To try and acheive this, I added the following to the beginning of my test file before the auth middleware function is added to the app in `app.js`.

```
jest.mock('../../middleware/auth.js', () =>
  // ensure func is mocked before being attached to the app instance
  jest.fn((req, res, next) => next()) // seems to only work for first request that hits this middleware
); // Mock authentication
```

I then added some debugs in the auth middleware but did not hit them for any of the tests.

Currently I am using the following, when the `beforeEach()` function is not commented out the tests all pass:

role.test.js

```
jest.mock('../../middleware/auth.js', () =>
  // ensure func is mocked before being attached to the app instance
  jest.fn((req, res, next) => next()) // seems to only work for first request that hits this middleware
); // Mock authentication

const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../../app.js');
const Role = require('../../../db/models/index.js').Role;
// const auth = require('../../middleware/auth.js');
/**
 * Test role API routes
 */
describe('role-router', () => {
  let res;
  const token = 'valid-token';
  const baseUrl = '/private/api/roles';

  // Without the `beforeEach()` only the first request sent using supertest will use the mocked functionality
  // With the `beforeEach()` everything functions as expected, but why?
  // beforeEach(() => {
  //   auth.mockImplementation((req, res, next) => next());
  // });

  describe(`Create new role | post ${baseUrl}`, () => {
    describe('When successful', () => {
      beforeAll(async () => {
        // this will use the proper mocked functionality
        res = await request(app)
          .post(baseUrl)
          .set('Authorization', token)
          .send({
            roleName: 'Secret Agent',
            roleDesc: "World's best secret agent",
            ...
          });
      });

      // passes
      it('Should return 201', () => {
        expect(res.status).toBe(201);
      });
    }); // When successful
  }); // Create new role

  describe(`Delete role by id | delete ${baseUrl}/:id`, () => {
    describe('When successful', () => {
      beforeAll(async () => {
        const role = await Role.create({
          roleName: 'Secret Agent',
          roleDesc: "World's best secret agent",
          ...
        });
        
        // fails does not get response, res remains the same as res from previous test
        res = await request(app)
          .delete(`${baseUrl}/${role.id}`)
          .set('Authorization', token)
          .send();
      });

      // fails with 201
      it('Should return 204', () => {
        expect(res.status).toBe(204);
      });
    }); // When successful
  }); // Delete role
});
```

Error received:

```
 ● role-router › Delete role by id | delete /private/api/roles/:id › When successful › Should return 204

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at mapper (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:29:45)
```

app.js

```
// Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const auth = require('./middleware/auth.js');
...

/**
 * Express application
 */
const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
...

// Private routes are secured with jwt authentication middleware
app.all('/private/*', (req, res, next) => auth(req, res, next));

// Public routes
...

// Private routes
app.use('/private/api/roles/', require('./components/role/role-router.js'));
...

module.exports = app;
```

Any ideas why this is not working without using the `beforeEach()` function to mock the middleware functionality before every test? Perhaps I am missing something more serious?

Comment: The only possibility I see that is related to `auth` is that you have resetMocks enabled. In any other case `jest.fn(() => ...)` in jest.mock shouldn't be different from `auth.mockImplementation`. In case this is true, consider replacing resetMocks with restoreMocks.

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask, the resetMocks configuration parameter was indeed true. Setting it to false solved the problem.

Comment: Glad it was that simple. Posted an answer in case somebody has a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for such behaviour is that there is `spy.mockReset()`, `jest.resetAllMocks()` or enabled `resetMocks` configuration option. Use `restoreMocks` option instead for a reasonable default configuration.

The difference between `jest.fn(() => ...)` and `jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ...)` is how they respond to `jest.restoreAllMocks()`. `restoreAllMocks` restores original implementation which is a no-op in case of `jest.fn()`, while `() => ...` is considered original implementation in case of `jest.fn(...)`. So normally `jest.fn(() => ...)` implementation isn't expected to be reset.

The difference between `jest.resetAllMocks` and `jest.restoreAllMocks` is that the former can make `jest.fn(...)` a noop but doesn't restore spies to original implementations. This specifically affects spies that are provided in mocked modules once per test suite with `jest.mock`, yet still doesn't restore global spies. Since this behaviour is rarely desirable, `jest.restoreAllMocks()` or `restoreMocks` configuration option are generally preferable. In case there's ever a need for `jest.fn(...)` implementation to be reset, `mockReset` or `mockImplementation` can be done specifically for this spy.